# How to respond to interface orientation changes?

Tags: iphone

I know the app delegate can say "yo man, I want thais new landscape orientation!" or "no thanks, don't want landscape!" and then the device won't do it.

How to implement this?

Comment: Yo! I want this landscape orientation, fo shizzle! Gimme!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The active view controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method determines whether the interface will rotate.

For launch, there is a key in your Info.plist file that needs to be set if you want to be able to launch in orientations other than portrait.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to get the orientation notification by registering UIDeviceDidChangeOrientationNotification. The delegate of UIViewController about orientation always confuses me. I prefer to control the animation effect by myself.